# Странно работающий float в С++

Tags: python, c++, float

Я Python-программист, только начинаю осваивать С++. Решил написать функцию для вычисления процента из данных - сколько всего, и сколько из. Мой код был фактически переведён с кода на Python, в код на С++. В то время, как код на Python работает как положено, вот он:

```
def percent(frst, scnd):
    coef = 100 / frst
    res = scnd * coef
    return res
```

При входных данных в виде `6400, 234`, выдаётся результат:

```
3.65625
```

А вот его "порт" на C++:

```
float Percent (int first, int second) {
    float coefficient = 100 / first;
    float result = second * coefficient;
    return result;
}
```

При тех же самых входных данных, почему-то, результатом является:

```
0.000000%
```

Компилятор - g++ (GCC) 10.2.1 20201203.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Измените сигнатуру функции:

```cpp
float Percent(float first, float second);
```

Ошибка происходит потому, что сначала Вы делите целое на целое, а уже затем преобразуете результат, т.е. ноль, в тип с плавающей запятой. Происходит это в строке 2:

```cpp
float coefficient = 100 / first;  // 100 / 6400 = 0
```

---

**P.S.:**

Стоит сказать, что код на C++ не является аналогом кода на Python. Python в большинстве случаев [использует](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#representation-error) для представления чисел с плавающей запятой тип `double`:

> Almost all platforms map Python floats to IEEE-754 “double precision”. 754 doubles contain 53 bits of precision

Поэтому более точным аналогом была бы следующая функция:

```cpp
double Percent(double first, double second)
{
    double coefficient = 100 / first;
    double result = second * coefficient;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю. Правда уже сам справился, понял, что необходимо перевести из int в float.

Comment: @ctwrd: не забудьте пометить ответ «принятым» (зелёная галочка), и проголосовать за него (оранжевая стрелка вверх). Сделав это, вы таким образом поблагодарите пользователя, который написал вам ответ.